# Using one thread to do a specific task multiple times C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a class that works with a device, to avoid delays in UI layer when working with device and serial port I used a thread, but my device is limited to do only one job at a time.
So, I have a queue that when user asks to do something tasks got added to it, then I run a thread to do tasks one by one.

Every time user asks for a task I check if the thread is running or not, if yes I just add new task to queue, if not I create thread again. Which means each time queue got empty, I should create a new thread. Now I want to ask is there any way to reuse the thread? Since I just need one thread to do tasks is it a good idea to use threadpool? Since suspend is an obsolete method and I don't know when the user would ask for another task to use wait(), can I suspend thread and run it again in any other way? or It is best to create thread again and I'm doing it right?

```
public class Modem
{
    Thread thread;
    Queue<Task> Tasks = new Queue<Task>();
    public Modem()
    {
    }

    public void DoTask(Task s)
    {
        Tasks.Enqueue(s);
        if (thread == null || !thread.IsAlive)
           thread = new Thread(HandleTasks);
    }

    private void HandleTasks()
    {
        while (Tasks.Count != 0)
            SendTaskToModem(Tasks.Dequeue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why write your own ThreadPool? The framework already provides one.

Comment: How about using a thread pool instead? Sounds like it is what you want.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Isn't threadpool useful in cases of multiple threads? I mean I can't run more that one thread to pick tasks from queue and pass them to modem, actually I need a thread to do tasks one by one! Or I am misunderstanding threadpool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to reuse the thread? Since I just need one thread to
>   do tasks is it a good idea to use threadpool?

Yes, using the `ThreadPool` and relying on the framework is usually a better idea then spinning up your own custom implementation.

What you can do is use one background thread which is responsible for processing your items while another is responsible for queuing them. This is a simple producer-consumer problem. For that, you can use a `BlockingCollection`:

```
public class Modem
{
    private BlockingCollection<Task> _tasks;
    public Modem()
    {
       _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    }

    public void QueueTask(Task s)
    {
        _tasks.Add(s);
    }

    private Task StartHandleTasks()
    {
         return Task.Run(async () =>
         {
             while (!_tasks.IsCompleted)
             {
                 if (_tasks.Count == 0)
                 {
                     await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
                     continue;
                 }

                 Task task;
                 _tasks.TryTake(out task);

                 if (task != null)
                 {
                    // Process item.
                 }
             }
         });
    }
}
```

This is a rather simplistic example of using a `BlockingCollection`. It has more built-in features such as using a `CancellationToken` to cancel an item currently being processed. Note you will have to add proper exception handling, cancellation, etc.

@ChrFin implementation using `TPL Dataflow` saves you some overhead in starting up the processing of the tasks and spinning the background thread while there aren't any items to process. I posted this answer to give you another way of solving your problem.

Comment: Why implement your own "producer-consumer" logic if there is already one built in? How would you handle errors in the "free running task"?

Comment: How is this implementing my own producer-consumer logic? this is simply using built-in types for what he needs. I'm not sure the OP needs to full blown architecture of `TPL Dataflow`, especially when you limit its concurrency to a single thread? How would i handle errors? im not sure what you mean. How is this any different than handling errors in any processing of a queue?

Comment: As i said in my answer, it is a rather simplistic example. The OP will need to take this an make it built for all possible scenarios, including adding an error handling mechanism. Im not saying this example is better than using an `ActionBlock`, it's just a different one. Its up to the OP to decide what he wants to use.

Comment: That, is a matter of opinion my friend. I'm not creating an implementation of a producer-consumer queue myself, im using the built-in type i get from the framework, without having to install a third-party nuget library. BTW, as i said, im not even sure he needs to full blown power of `TPL Dataflow` here. Those tasks need to execute sequentially anyway.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and giving me a good point of view. May I ask what happens after queue get empty? And who should call StartHandleTasks? After all, is it a bad idea to create thread again and again?

Comment: @SamanHakimzadehAbyaneh: Here you just need to call `StartHandleTasks` once and it will run (and block a thread BTW) until the `BlockingCollection` is completed. The `ActionBlock` takes care of this for you (and also only blocks a thread when there is actually something to process).

Comment: @SamanHakimzadehAbyaneh It is up to you to decide who calls `StartHandleTasks` in your implementation. You should also add a check to make sure it isn't initialized already.

Comment: @ChrFin: I still don't get it! Imagine the queue get empty, then user asks for another task, so the queue has an item now, you mean it automatically will handle it or I should call StartHandleTasks again?!

Comment: @SamanHakimzadehAbyaneh: It will handle it automatically. The Task/Block is still running (as long as you do not "complete it") and will pick up your new task as soon as it is available.

Comment: @ChrFin I've added a `Task.Delay`. Again, this isn't a production code example. It is an answer to get the OP started using a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: @ChrFin Im using `continue` so it'll loop again instead of try to dequeue an empty collection.

Comment: Thanks, I understand - makes more sense then just "assume something was added" in the 100ms and simply "let it run to the `TryTake`"...

Answer (score 2):

There is something built-in for such tasks: [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) (not distributed with the core framework, you need to add the `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` NuGet package).
If you create it like:

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<TASK>(t => DoWork(t), 
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });
```

only one item will be processed at once.

Then you simply call:

```
actionBlock.Post(yourTask);
```

and all "posted" tasks are executed one after each other in their own thread.

When you are done you can call `actionBlock.Complete();` and then e.g. `await actionBlock.Completion;`. There you can also check for exceptions which happend inside `DoWork`.